# SQL server 2008, datediff returns wrong value

Tags: sql-server-2008, datediff

I have two columns of Data type time. I'm using datediff to find the difference in hours.
The problem is when I try to find the difference between 00:00:00 to 06:00:00, it returns -18.
How can I fix it?
note: I need to calculate more difference with this so I can't just divide it with -3

```
my function- (datediff(HOUR, startHour, endHour))*60
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Dividing by -3 would only yield the correct result in this special case. Replace 06:00:00 by 07:00:00 and you'll see that I mean.

Comment: Can you post some code and data that shows the problem? Testing what you say gives `6` as a result. [Try here](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/69325)

Comment: What datatypes are startHour and endHour?

Comment: In my (clearly twisted from reading math for long periods) eyes, `-18` and `6` are the same thing when ones works in `mod 24 hours` mode. Much like as `17:00` and `5:00` is the same when one works in `mod 12` mode.

Comment: If the above comment is obscure: Do a `mod 24` operation on the result.

Answer (score 3):

You are not comparing `00:00:00` to `06:00:00`. You have some date component

This gives -18 as an example

```
DECLARE @starthour datetime = '00:00:00';
DECLARE @endhour datetime = '18991231 06:00:00';    
SELECT @starthour, @endhour, DATEDIFF(hour, @starthour, @endhour); 

SET @starthour = '20120507 00:00:00';
SET @endhour = '20120506 06:00:00';
SELECT @starthour, @endhour, DATEDIFF(hour, @starthour, @endhour);
```

Comment: Thanks, but startHour and endHour are from datatype time hh:mm:ss , without date

Comment: @user1232948: check and double check please: I've just demonstrated how to get -18...

Comment: I don't want -18 or 18, I want 6 :)

Comment: @user1232948: well, you can't because you have an end value before your start value. Simple. it is the **only** way to get a negative value...

Comment: I have in the table 4 shifts: 06:00-12:00, 12:00-18:00, 18:00-00:00 and 00:00-06:00 (the first hour is startHour, the second is endHour). The only pair that I have problem with is 00:00-06:00

Comment: @user1232948 Are you sure about what row gives you trouble? Because `18:00-00:00` will give you `-18`.

Comment: Mikael you are right. It's 18:00-00:00 that cause trouble. My apologies. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: @user1232948 update your question with this information and ask for another way to represent the intervals. `time` will not work for you.

Comment: @user1232948 I would probably use `time(0)` for startHour and a `smallint` for the duration in minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Reverse the parameters:

```
my function- (datediff(HOUR, endHour, startHour))*60
```

Edit:

The function DATEDIFF works with dates and for some reason, it thinks you're subtracting 6AM - Midnight (next day), which is 18 hours.

The following code sample works fine for me in SQL 2008, so you need to check your data type to make sure you're using TIME and not DATETIME or SMALLDATETIME.

```
declare @t1 time
set @t1 = '00:00:00'
declare @t2 time 
set @t2 = '06:00:00'

select datediff(hour, @t1, @t2)

-- returns 6
```

Comment: I tried to reverse them but it just returned 18. And I need to calculate more time differences with it anyway.

Comment: gbn- the startHour and endHour are from datatype time

Comment: I'm using time. When I tried it like that I got 6, but when I pull it from the table I get 18.

Comment: Can you post your table structure, scripted from SQL Mgmt Studio?

Answer (score 0):

### Syntax:

```
DATEDIFF (datepart, startdate, enddate )
```

### Examples:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(hour, '00:00:00', '06:00:00');
```

**Result: 6**

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(hour, '00:00:00', '06:00:00')*60;
```

**Result: 360**

Refer **[DATEDIFF (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)**

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the game, but I faced a similar problem.

```
DATEDIFF(HOUR,'23:00:00','06:00:00')
```

**Result:  -17**

Reversing the two times (as suggested by another answer above) does not represent the time frame I want to capture.  I don't want to know how many hours are between 6am and 11pm.  I want 11pm to 6am.

To resolve this, wrap the `DATEDIFF()` in a `CASE` statement and add 24 when the start time is greater than the end time:

```
DECLARE @startTime TIME(0) = '23:00:00';
DECLARE @endTime TIME(0) = '06:00:00';
SELECT CASE WHEN @startTime > @endTime THEN 24 + DATEDIFF(HOUR,@startTime,@endTime) ELSE DATEDIFF(HOUR,@startTime,@endTime) END
```

**Result: 7**